# How to make it so when a button is clicked a div shows and when a different button is clicked it hides that div and displays a different one

Tags: javascript, html, css, show

how to make it so when you click a button it shows a div and hides the one ur on

example: if you have "profile" & "dashboard" and you click "dashboard" it shows the div for dashboard and hides the one for profile

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.style` to hide the div, but it would be better to use seperate pages (EX: https://example.com/profile and https://example.com/dashboard).

```js
(() => {
  window.onload = () => {
    const profilediv = document.getElementById(`profile`);
    const dashboarddiv = document.getElementById(`dashboard`);
    const profilebutton = document.getElementById(`profilebutton`);
    const dashboardbutton = document.getElementById(`dashboardbutton`);
    var page = 0;

    function updatePage() {
      profilediv.style.display = `none`;
      dashboarddiv.style.display = `none`;
      if (page == 0) {
        dashboarddiv.style.display = `block`;
      } else if (page == 1) {
        profilediv.style.display = `block`;
      }
      return;
    }
    profilebutton.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
      page = 1;
      setTimeout(updatePage);
      return;
    });
    dashboardbutton.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
      page = 0;
      setTimeout(updatePage);
      return;
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#profile,
#dashboard {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}

#topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#profilebutton,
#dashboardbutton {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <button id="dashboardbutton">Dashboard</button>
  <button id="profilebutton">Profile</button>
</div>
<div id="dashboard" style="display: block;">
  <p>Dashboard</p>
</div>
<div id="profile" style="display: none;">
  <p>Test Account</p>
  <button>Edit Name</button>
</div>
```